# Mysql query optimisation - sum() function

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `clicks_summ` (
    `dt` INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `banner` SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `client` SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `channel` SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `cnt` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `lpid` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `dt` (`dt`, `banner`, `client`, `channel`, `lpid`),
    INDEX `banner` (`banner`),
    INDEX `channel` (`channel`),
    INDEX `client` (`client`),
    INDEX `lpid` (`lpid`),
    INDEX `cnt` (`cnt`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and i am using following query to fetch rows/records from this table:

```
 select client, sum(cnt) cnt
 from clicks_summ cs
 group by client;
```

and it's awful! It takes about a second to perform this query. `EXPLAIN` shows me
[image: Explain SQL Statement result]

So, the question is: how I can speed up this query? I've tried indexing this table on different fields without any reasonable success. Now there are `331 036` rows in this table, I guess, is not so big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try craete `INDEX client_cnt(client, cnt)`. Another way to make query faster is upgrade your hardware:)

Comment: That helped me, thanks! This query is a part of a bigger one, so I'll test the whole thing and post the result!

Answer (score 0):

one cool thing

if you always have 5 col in your where clause when a grouped index of 5 col will outperform 5 individual indexes ;)